# Install RTC ifix version using eclipse p2 director

Tags: conflict, rational-team-concert

I wanted to install RTC ifix version in my local eclipse using p2generator. When I tried installing the package manually it installs for me properly, and when i install the same package through ANT script I am facing issue and it is not getting installed and facing the below issue:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Enterprise Common Build UI 1.3.100.v20180217_0421 (com.ibm.team.enterprise.build.ui 1.3.100.v20180217_0421)
  Software currently installed: Rational Team Concert Client Feature 4.5.800.v20171103_2316 (com.ibm.team.rtc.client.feature.feature.group 4.5.800.v20171103_2316)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
   Enterprise Common Build UI 1.3.100.v20171020_1727 (com.ibm.team.enterprise.build.ui 1.3.100.v20171020_1727)
   Enterprise Common Build UI 1.3.100.v20180217_0421 (com.ibm.team.enterprise.build.ui 1.3.100.v20180217_0421)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
   From: Enterprise Extensions Build UI Feature 1.2.1300.v20171103_0616 (com.ibm.team.enterprise.build.feature.ui.feature.group 1.2.1300.v20171103_0616)
   To: com.ibm.team.enterprise.build.ui [1.3.100.v20171020_1727]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
   From: Rational Team Concert Client Feature 4.5.800.v20171103_2316 (com.ibm.team.rtc.client.feature.feature.group 4.5.800.v20171103_2316)
   To: com.ibm.team.enterprise.build.feature.ui.feature.group [1.2.1300.v20171103_0616]
 Application failed
```

I am taking the unit id's to install from content.xml of the package, and since it does not have the category I am taking the "unit id" and passing for installation in a loop.

I wanted to install the package through script also, and due to this issue I could not get a clue even.

In the issue one version of plugin got installed during RTC installation and another version which I am installing now is ifix version. But I need both the versions to be installed here. How to install same plugin with different versions in eclipse ?

Any inputs would be really appreciated. Thanks !